# Scala: Overload (Seq[T]) and (T*)

Tags: scala, types, overloading, type-erasure

I have a case class, taking a Seq[T] as parameter:

```
case class MyClass(value: Seq[T])
```

I now want to be able to write

```
MyClass(t1,t2,t3)
```

So I defined

```
object MyClass {
    def apply(value: T*) = new MyClass(value.toSeq)
}
```

It doesn't work, because the case class defines

```
object MyClass {
    def apply(value: Seq[T])
}
```

and Seq[T] and T* have the same type after erasure, so I can't overload them.

But I'd like to allow both access ways. Both ways should be allowed:

```
MyClass(t1,t2,t3)
MyClass(some_seq_of_T)
```

Since Seq[T] and T* are almost the same type (at least after erasure; and inside of the function having the parameter T* becomes Seq[T]), I think there should be a way to allow both ways of calling it.

Is there?

Comment: Is T some concrete type or your `MyClass` has a type parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could cheat a little bit and define your companion like this:

```
case class MyClass[T](value: Seq[T])

object MyClass {
  def apply[T](first: T, theRest: T*) = new MyClass(first :: theRest.toList)
  def apply[T]() = new MyClass[T](Nil)
}
```

The first `apply` handles the `MyClass(1,2,3)` as long as there is at least one argument.
The scond `apply` handles the 0-argument case. They don't conflict with the regular constructor.

This way you can write `MyClass(Seq(1,2,3))`, `MyClass(1,2,3)`, and `MyClass()`. Just note that for the empty one you'll have to tell it what type to return, or else it will assume a `MyClass[Nothing]`

Comment: That's an unreadable hack. And for what? To avoid giving the factory method a different name.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution without case classes:

```
scala> class A[T] (ts: Seq[T]) { def this(ts: T*)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = this(ts) }
defined class A

scala> new A(1)
res0: A[Int] = A@2ce62a39

scala> new A(Seq(1))
res1: A[Seq[Int]] = A@68634baf
```

Comment: Why does this work? The constructor is overloaded the same way as in the question, I think.

Comment: @Heinzi - No, there is an additional argument (implicit). And since implicits are resolved before type erasure, compiler is able to figure the stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be two methods of the same name where one takes a parameter of type `Seq[T]` and one takes `T*`. How would the compiler know whether a call like

```
val s = Seq(1,2,3) 
foo(s)
```

is supposed to call the first method or the second method (with T = Int) or the second one (with T = Seq[Int]) ?